# My Pygame script makes my character on screen pause when my mouse is moved

Tags: pygame

I wanted to make a simple game in pygame where i moved the character(a square) with WASD keys. I have somewhat achieved that but the movement is not smooth and when i move my mouse the character refuses to move.

I assume it is something to do with my for loop

```
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type is pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

I know it is stuck in the loop whilst there is input but i'm not sure how to fix it without not being able to close the program.

Here is the main game loop:

```
while launchGame:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type is pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    player.draw()
    player.move()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

And here is my move script if that helps:

```
    def move(self):
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_w]:
            self.y -= self.speed
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_s]:
            self.y += self.speed
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_a]:
            self.x -= self.speed
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_d]:
            self.x += self.speed
```

How can I fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple typo. In the second line you have `if event.type is pygame.QUIT:`

And should be `if event.type == pygame.QUIT:`

If this didn't work, try:

```
while RUNNING:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type is pygame.QUIT:
            RUNNING = False;
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    player.draw()
    player.move()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

And run the program from the command line to see if it's a problem with pycharm

Comment: It dosen't make a difference, its the same effect.

Comment: Do you have errors? What IDE are you using? Maybe you can try using
 `while RUNNING`  and instead of 
    `pygame.quit()`
    `sys.exit()`
do a `RUNNING = False`

If this don't work either. Post the full code or github repo and I will check it out

Comment: No errors, i'm using pycharm, and i tried the RUNNING = False but it still didn't work.

Comment: @Michael run the program from the command line and tell me what happens

Comment: Same issue, it moves the square then when i move my mouse the square stops.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I don't need if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: if i'm using pygame.key.get_pressed() because it's not an event function.

Thanks but no thanks i guess xD